# Logging AssertionError exceptions & pytest unit testing in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, pytest, assertion

I've been implementing logging to my python app, and I've stumbled upon what looks like a contradiction between unit testing & logging. I'm looking for the best practice here, thanks in advance for your help !

```py
# app.py
def my_function(foo: int) -> int:
   assert isinstance(foo, (int))

   return foo * 2
```

The associated unit test

```py
# test_my_function.py
import pytest
from app import my_function

def test_wrong_type_input():
    test_input = '3'

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        my_function(test_input)
```

The two files above work OK, and the unit test campaign ends with a successful status.
However, I'm implementing logging to my app and I noticed that if I do pass an object other than a `int` to my function, **the AssertionError is not passed to the logger**, and this would lead to a more complicated root cause analysis in production.

Looking for answers on this, the `logging` documentation mentions capturing exception with a `try/except` statement. The new `app.py` would be the following :

```py
# app.py
import logging

def my_function(foo: int) -> int:
    try:
        assert isinstance(foo, (int))
    except:
        logging.exception("Input `foo` did not meet the function's requirements")

    return foo * 2
```

However, now my unit test fails because the AssertionError is captured by the `try/except`.

What's the best practice here ?
How can I get both :

- getting the full traceback in logs when experiencing an Exception
- while still be able to use the `pytest.raises(AssertionError)` logic ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You have to decide what the behavior of your function shall be. If you want to catch the exception, you cannot test it (and there is no need to test it, as it would be an internal implementation detail). In your case, this is probably not a good idea, as it would return a wrong value, or crash. If you just want to add logging before the exception, you can re-raise the exception after the log (just call `raise`), and test for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MrBean Bremen, indeed, I was able to get the exception via a `raise` statement, although I guess I should specific the different exception cases to avoid a catch-all situation.

```py
# app.py
import logging

def my_function(foo: int) -> int:
    try:
        assert isinstance(foo, (int))
    except:
        logging.exception("Input `foo` did not meet the function's requirements")
        raise(AssertionError)

    return foo * 2
```

Comment: If you want to re-raise an exception just use the `raise` statement - that will re-raise the current exception instead of creating a new (unspecific) one. Though in this case it doesn't make much sense to first use `assert` and than catch it - just check for the type using `isinstance` and raise a `TypeError` if it is not `int`.